# customize comment form

Tags: comments, html, comment-form, comments-template

I want to change the titles "Name", "Email", and "Website" in my comment form?.  How could I do this?  I thought by changing them in this field would work ( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) but it doesn't change anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my comments.php

```html
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h4 id="comments"><?php comments_number('No Comments', 'One Comment', '% Comments' );?></h4>
    <ol class="comment-list">
<?php wp_list_comments('callback=custom_comments');?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    $comments_args = array(
  'id_form'           => 'commentform',
  'class_form'      => 'comment-form',
  'id_submit'         => 'submit',
  'class_submit'      => 'submit',
  'name_submit'       => 'submit',
  'title_reply'       => __( 'Post a comment' ),
  'title_reply_to'    => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s' ),
  'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Cancel Reply' ),
  'label_submit'      => __( 'Post Comment' ),
  'format'            => 'xhtml',




  'comment_field' =>  '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Join the Conversation', 'noun' ) .
    '</label><textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' .
    '</textarea></p>',

  'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' .
    sprintf(
      __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
      wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' .
    sprintf(
    __( ' <a href="</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account"></a>' ),
      admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
      $user_identity,
      wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' .
    __( '' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) .
    '</p>',


 'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',          







);
    comment_form($comments_args);
?>
```

Also kind of unrelated to the question.  The comment form shows up first and is then followed by the Name, Email, and Website forms.  Is there a way to make it so that the Name, Email, and Website forms are first followed by the comment form last?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will allow you to customize the comment field labels and will move the comment form below the fields. Add the code to your `functions.php` or to a plugin.

To change the labels, modify the `Name CUSTOMIZED`, `Email CUSTOMIZED`, and `Website CUSTOMIZED`, and `Comment * CUSTOMIZED` text.

```
/**
 * Customize comment form default fields.
 * Move the comment_field below the author, email, and url fields.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields( $fields ) {
    $commenter     = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $user          = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_identity = $user->exists() ? $user->display_name : '';
    $req           = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req      = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
    $html_req      = ( $req ? " required='required'" : '' );
    $html5         = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'comment-form' ) ? 'html5' : false;

    $fields = [
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name CUSTOMIZED', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="245"' . $aria_req . $html_req . ' /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email CUSTOMIZED', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="email"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="100" aria-describedby="email-notes"' . $aria_req . $html_req  . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website CUSTOMIZED', 'textdomain'  ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="url"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="200" /></p>',
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment * CUSTOMIZED', 'noun', 'textdomain' ) . '</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p>',
    ];

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields' );

/**
 * Remove the original comment field because we've added it to the default fields
 * using wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields(). If we don't do this, the comment
 * field will appear twice.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
    if ( isset( $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] ) ) {
        $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] = '';
    }

    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse250243_comment_form_defaults', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Where does `$html5` come from?

Comment: Good catch. Initialized `$html5` in updated code. Also initialized`$html_req`.