# comment_form() Not changing the default class/id of elements

Tags: comment-form

**EDIT** I am trying to change the class and id of the `<form>` element and well as the `<input>`/Submit button field using the `comment_form()` function. How ever it appears that various string values are being echoed out instead of replacing the default values (see demo link).

**CODE:**

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

    <?php
        $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
        $aria_req = ( $req ? ' aria-required="true"' : '' );

        $fields = array(
            'id_form'       => 'comment-form',
            'class_form'    => 'form-inline',
            'class_submit'  => 'btn btn-default',
            'author'        => '<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment-author" class="sr-only">' . __( 'Author', 'magneton' ) . '</label>
                                <input type="text" name="author" id="comment-author" class="form-control" placeholder="' . __( 'Author (required)', 'magneton' ) . '"' . $aria_req . '>',
            'email'         => '<label for="comment-author-email" class="sr-only">' . __( 'E-Mail', 'magneton' ) . '</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="comment-author-email" class="form-control" placeholder="' . __( 'E-Mail (required)', 'magneton' ) . '"' . $aria_req . '>',
            'url'            => '<label for="comment-author-url" class="sr-only">' . __( 'Website', 'magneton' ) . '</label>
                                <input type="url" name="url" id="comment-author-url" class="form-control" placeholder="' . __( 'Website'. 'magneton' ) . '">
                                </div>'
        );

        $comments_args = array(
            'fields' => $fields,
            'title_reply' => __( 'Leave a reply', 'magneton' ),
            'comment_field' => '<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control"  aria-required="true" rows="10"></textarea>',
            'label_submit' => __( 'Submit Comment', 'magneton' )
        );
    ?>

    <?php comment_form( $comments_args ); ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

**LINK:** [DEMO](http://magneton.carbonium.no/aenean-fringilla-nunc-at-lorem-porttitor-dictum/)

Comment: Move the `id_form`, `class_form`, and `class_submit` items out of `$fields` and into the `$comments_args` array (alongside `title_reply`, `comment_field`, etc). See [`comment_form()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).

Comment: @DaveRomsey, thank i looked over the documentation (again) and you are correct. I swear sometime i get so blind looking at code. You should make this an answer so i can check it off. Also one last question, is there any way to re-arrange the order of the fields?

Comment: Thank you! I've added an answer and linked to another solution that covers rearranging and customizing the comment form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes are being rendered inline because the `id_form`, `class_form`, and `class_submit` parameters should be placed within the `$comments_args` array (alongside `title_reply`, `comment_field`, etc) and not within the `$fields` array. See [comment_form()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).

> Also one last question, is there any way to re-arrange the order of
>   the fields?

Yes, the fields can be reordered. [Here's an answer that shows how to accomplish reordering and customizing the comment fields.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250243/customize-comment-form/250246#250246) The main gotcha with reordering the comment fields is that if you want the main comment field to appear above the name/email/URL/etc fields, the `comment_form_defaults` filter needs to be used to set `$comment_field` to an empty string. This is because of how the parameters are set up; `$comment_field` is special and not part of the `$fields` array by default. This is covered in the answer linked above.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Comment: I hate to bother you again, but just as i was all happy that code worked as presented in your link, i come to realize none of the custom form fields are visible when i am logged in to my wordpress installation. Any idea ?

Comment: No worries! That's a good question. [Here's an answer that covers that, and more.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248959/2807)

Comment: Thanks, i will have  read through the various links i am sure i will find the answere!

Comment: Sure! The two most relevant sections will be *Register and display meta box on comment edit screen* and *Handle updating the comment meta data*.

Comment: Acctually, i solved this by simply changing the `$comments_arg` array to include the `['comment_field']` value IF a user is logged in, using `is_user_logged_in()`. Since i am only using default fields such as name, email and url. This worked as expected. Not sure if it is hacky or not. The acctual fields for user/email/url are only relevant if the commenter is not logged in.

Comment: Ah, ok good! I misunderstood your followup question.

Comment: No worries, i appreciate the link, it helped me realize that the fields i was using where in fact native to WordPress and that my own solution would in fact work. So again, thank you.